# How to save data in checkout after refresh page Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2.1

How I can save data in checkout after refresh page Magento 2. Data writes into.
[mage-cache-storage Local Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k844t.png) But after refresh it's flush. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity it's not programming?????? really?

Comment: Yes, really. There's no question here about programming. The question talks about technical things - "data", "cache", "flush", etc. You can program against those things, but you don't have to. This question - on face value - might be about turning on a config setting. You need to ask an explicit programming-related question. Showing your code and telling us what is wrong with it would be a good way to do that.